# REACT - map immutable dynamic state in array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am dynamically creating input fields on a page to add new users to a contact book. For each user i create with an on click event, i append a new user object to an array. This object then gets dynamic state placed within its properties, so i can updated each with the input fields i create that set the value of those items. However i am unable to access or change the objects in the users array. What can i do to solve this?

```
appendUser() {
  let usersLength = this.state.users.length;
  let newUser = {
    name : '',
    age : '',
    birthday : '',
  };

  this.setState({ users: this.state.users.concat([newUser]) });  

  for (let i = 0; i < usersLength; i++) {
    updateItem(i, this.state.users[i] = {
        name : this.state.users[i].name,
        age : this.state.users[i].age,
        birthday : this.state.users[i].birthday,
      }
    )    
  }

}

updateItem(id, itemAttributes) {
  let index = this.state.users.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
  if (index === -1) {
    console.error('error in update')
  } else {
    this.setState({
      users: [
       ...this.state.users.slice(0,index),
       Object.assign({}, this.state.users[index], itemAttributes),
       ...this.state.users.slice(index+1)
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

My input form component which creates the fields on click:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.users.map((user, index) =>
        <formgroup key={index}>
          <input name={'name'} type="string" onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.name} required />
          <input name={'age'} type="string" onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.age} required />
          <input name={'birthday'} type="string" onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.birthday} required />
        </formgroup>
      )}
        <button onClick={ this.props.appendUser }>Add Another User</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and the handleChange function

```
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }
```

Comment: what values do you get in this.props.users ?

Comment: @HarshMakadia just an array of empty objects i initialize with newUser variable